# How can I insert a link into a latex environment in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have the following file open in Org mode:

```
* Headline 1

[[Headline 1]]

\begin{enumerate}
\item yes %[[Headline 1]]
\item no
\end{enumerate}
```

When I click the first link to `Headline 1`, I jump to it, as expected. When I click the second link, emacs tells me `No link found`. When I remove the latex environment the second link works again. Why is this happening?
I want to have a clickable link in my latex environment. How can I create such a link?

Comment: Why do you use the LaTeX `enumerate`-environment and not just `1.`?

Comment: @Tobias I like how it looks, when the latex environment gets rendered with latex preview. ^^

Comment: But then as far as Org mode is concerned, the environment is a black box, so Org mode cannot see what is inside it.

Comment: @NickD okay, thank you. I didn't know this. I guess then this doesn't work ^^